# Increment a variable to be compared inside an if

Tags: c

```
if (++bufCnt >= smenu->bufSize)  //line1
if (bufCnt++ >= smenu->bufSize)  //line2
```

In line1 bfrCnt is first incremented and then compared. In line2 it is first compared and then incremented. Is this correct?

Comment: Why don't you increment it before the if? You know the length of your code doesn't affect the efficiency of it?

Comment: @Jan Hudec. I have already debugged, but I am going to change it in all my routines, so I want to be 100% sure.

Comment: @Gui13: That's what I though also, but I just saw that I gain 2 bytes in this way. And in real time systems it matters! If this is done inside all my files, then we are talknig about some hunfreads of bytes maybe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,
In line1 bfrCnt is first incremented and then compared.
In line2 it is first compared and then incremented.
Your question is not having the quality when it is compared to the other questions in this site. That is why you are getting down votes.
So when ever you are posting a question, make sure it is having enough standard.

Comment: Thank you sarin jacob, I just read the FAQs. I didn't know that general elementary questions are not allowed. I will follow forum rules next time. I am kindly asking one of the moderators to delete this thread, since it is against forum rules.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.
In both case you increase bufCnt.
But without else if you increase bufCnt two times.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But what do you mean by that? Why two times? I am going to use only line 1.

Comment: When you use both lines (whyever) and the first if statement is false, you increment bufCount a second time in line2.